# Как НЕ размыть фоновое изображение?

Tags: html, css

Моё фоновое изображение имеет маленькое разрешение и браузер его размывает. Мне нужно наоборот сделать границы пикселей резкими.

Comment: @Greg-- а просто отменить размытие нельзя? Я просто хочу пиксельный фон.

Comment: Попробуйте задать для изобрадения `image-rendering: pixelated;` могут конечно вылазить баги  на границах

Comment: Может лучше будет `image-rendering: crisp-edges` конечно у pixelated поддержка браузерами скудная

Comment: Одна из методик - [фильтр в канвасе](https://konvajs.org/docs/filters/Pixelate.html) сделать, проще - [фильтр в svg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37451883/14135825) тогда получится контролируемый результат

Comment: Можно скриптами [Pixel IT](https://giventofly.github.io/pixelit/)

Comment: @Greg--, очень похоже, что наоборот. Хром вообще не понимает `crisp-edges`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
img {
  width: 180px;
  margin: 10px;
}

img + img {
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}
```

```html
<img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/GMjDY.png">
<img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/GMjDY.png">
```

Comment: не вижу разницы в фаирфоксе

Comment: @teran, кажется, только для хрома... Сейчас потыкаю FF.

Comment: @teran, готово, теперь и в FF работает.

Comment: Проверил Edge, Safari (desktop, Mac), Chrome (PC, Mac), Opera вроде работает, есть проблемы контролировать пиксельность и размер пикселя (чем больше пикселей тем хуже результат)

Comment: @Greg--, не понял про пиксели.

Comment: Когда очень маленькое изображение растягивается - получается красиво, когда сравнительно большое - получается ерунда, так как нет контроля размера клетки, шага. [Визуализация](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/i/image-rendering/#toggle-example) - в Toggle example заметно как это выглядит когда относительно много пикселей.

Comment: @yar85 я нигде не предлагал повысить качество.

Comment: В моём FF не работает, обе картинки размытые. Если я зайду в инструменты разработчика и перетыкну галочку возле `image-rendering: crisp-edges` у второй картинки, то пикселизуются ОБЕ картинки. Кажется, с моей лисой что-то не так...

Comment: @Greg--, о _качестве_ речи вообще не было... в общем, неважно, я уже понял что мой вопрос был не по адресу.

Comment: @andreymal, странно...